# Handling RuntimeExceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

Can anyone explain how to handle the Runtime Exceptions in Java?

Comment: I think the non-accepters of SO have figured out by now that those are empty threats.  We want mod points!

Comment: i never seen accept button anywhere ?

Comment: It's the big tick / correction mark beside an answer.

Comment: It's sad, but I have the impression that obvious 30-second answers to dumb questions usually give more reward points than well-written answers to more interesting questions. For questions with a high view rate, the first answer usually ends up with a lot of reward points even if it is not related to the question at all.

Comment: sorry, i could not find anywhere.

Comment: jarnbjo, that is a sad truth. eventually you'll get used to now being properly rewarded for your good and professional answers on hard questions ;)

Comment: @kalyaniRavi:  it's the check mark underneath the score for an answer.

Comment: @Danben: i checked, But i could not find the check mark underneath the score for accept the answer.

Comment: @kalyaniRavi: see, I took a screenshot, there is a clickable mark below the score and vote buttons: http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/checkmark.png

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It doesn't differ from handling a regular exception:

```
try {
   someMethodThatThrowsRuntimeException();
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
   // do something with the runtime exception
}
```

Comment: can catch the runtime exceptions..?

Comment: Of course! All subclasses of `Throwable` can be caught.

Comment: I dont see a problem with this question - I had a Runnable that I suspected was causing a runtime error and I wasn't aware that you could just wrap any code in a try/catch & add a RunTimeException catch. I Googled'Android handling runtime exceptions', this was the first question that came up & this answer provided what I needed. Surely thats exactly how SO should work?

Answer (score 4):

If you know the type of Exception that might be thrown, you could catch it explicitly.  You could also catch `Exception`, but this is generally considered to be very bad practice because you would then be treating Exceptions of all types the same way.

Generally the point of a RuntimeException is that you can't handle it gracefully, and they are not expected to be thrown during normal execution of your program.

Comment: Except, perhaps, when a custom component is throwing a RuntimeException because it can not reach a certain host over network and that is crashing your Android app.

Answer (score 3):

You just catch them, like any other exception.

```
try {
   somethingThrowingARuntimeException()
}
catch (RuntimeException re) {
  // Do something with it. At least log it.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're referring directly to `RuntimeException` in Java, so I'll assume you're talking about run-time exceptions.

The basic idea of exception handling in Java is that you encapsulate the code you expect might raise an exception in a special statement, like below.

```
try {
   // Do something here
}
```

Then, you handle the exception.

```
catch (Exception e) {
   // Do something to gracefully fail
}
```

If you need certain things to execute regardless of whether an exception is raised, add `finally`.

```
finally {
   // Clean up operation
}
```

All together it looks like this.

```
try {
   // Do something here
}
catch (AnotherException ex) {
}
catch (Exception e) {  //Exception class should be at the end of catch hierarchy.
}
finally {
}
```

Comment: can we catch the runtime exception? How it is possible? with out knowing the runtime exception, how we catch it programatically?

Comment: You can use `catch (ExceptionType name) {}` to catch any type of exception. Otherwise, you can use `catch {}` to catch all exceptions, or `catch (Exception name) {}` to catch all exceptions (and have the information about them accessible to you.

Comment: @Ed: It is correct.But if i got error on the server(loading issue).this is runtime exception.How we will catch this exception programatically? is it possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean...you catch exceptions programmatically using the syntax I gave you.