# java-how to handle runtime errors?

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm writing a java program that adds two numbers with any length(the input is string). it works well but the judge gives me 44 because it has "Runtime Error"
what should i do?

Comment: catch the exceptions.

Comment: there is no exception,it works for all the numbers

Comment: So what are those runtime errors ?

Comment: i don't know .the console works perfectly .it gives no error in any kind.  judge is the problem

Comment: Show the code you have, can't solve the problem if we can't see it.

Comment: Without any code or error log provided, it's virtually impossible for anyone to answer this. If the code is long as you say, paste it on a code-hosting site and link it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling RuntimeExceptions in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028719/handling-runtimeexceptions-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Answer your question "How to handle runtime-errors",

It is not different from any other exception:

```
try {

   someCode(); 

} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
   //handle runtime exception here
}
```

This judge may have given you a 44 (assuming that is low) because the input that comes to you as strings may not be numbers at all, and if this happens, your program should not crash? That would be my guess

**UPDATE:** Now that you have some code up, this is most likely the case, what happens if String a is "hello" ?  Your program would crash at `Long.parseLong()`, you need to handle this!

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your calls to `Long.parseLong`, by calls to such a method  :

```
private long checkLong(String entry){

long result = 0;
    try  
      {  
        result = Long.parseLong(entry);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException e)  
      {  
        System.out.println("Value " + entry + " is not valid") ; 
        System.exit(1);
      }

    return result;
}
```